# gmail api returning error 400 bad request

Tags: json, vb.net, google-api, gmail

I am trying to apply user settings to a Gmail account using the gmail API, but it keep returning error 400 bad request.

I can see the error code in the Gmail API console and its coming from my service account so the code cant be so wrong, but it is driving me crazy and just can not figure out what is wrong with it.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

```
    `Try

        Dim Gmail_Settings_Update As HttpWebRequest
        Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
        Dim postdata As String
        Dim postdatabytes As Byte()
        Dim Gmail_User As String = "Admin_account@gmail.com"

        '
        Gmail_Settings_Update = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Gmail_User) & "/settings/autoForwarding")

        enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        postdata = "{""enabled"":""true"",""emailAddress"":""Mail.forward@me.com"",""disposition"":""leaveInInbox""}"
        postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(postdata)

        Gmail_Settings_Update.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " & Token
        Gmail_Settings_Update.Method = "PUT"
        Gmail_Settings_Update.ContentType = "application/json"

        Gmail_Settings_Update.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length

        Using stream = Gmail_Settings_Update.GetRequestStream()

            stream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
        End Using
        Dim result = Gmail_Settings_Update.GetResponse()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a PUT request ? Are you sure you're using a valid Bearer Token ?

Comment: Yes its a PUT request, but I have resolved the issue myself. I needed "me" in the URI instead of the users email address

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue myself. I needed "me" in the URI instead of the users mail address